# How to read openapi json schema and extract API information using python

Tags: python, openapi

I have a openapi json schema file saved in my local PC. using a python script I want to read that json file and extract all the APIs defined in it (including API definition, request headers, request body etc...) and execute all those APIs in a loop.
API execution part I can handle but what I want to know is there any standard python library to read the openapi json spec to extract the API information.
If there is a standard python library could you please give me a sample code how to extract the API details out of this openapi json.

As an example please look at below openapi json schema.

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "Cat Facts API",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/breeds": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "Breeds"
                ],
                "summary": "Get a list of breeds",
                "description": "Returns a a list of breeds",
                "operationId": "getBreeds",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "limit",
                        "in": "query",
                        "description": "limit the amount of results returned",
                        "required": false,
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int64"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Breed"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/fact": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "Facts"
                ],
                "summary": "Get Random Fact",
                "description": "Returns a random fact",
                "operationId": "getRandomFact",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "max_length",
                        "in": "query",
                        "description": "maximum length of returned fact",
                        "required": false,
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int64"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CatFact"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "404": {
                        "description": "Fact not found"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/facts": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "Facts"
                ],
                "summary": "Get a list of facts",
                "description": "Returns a a list of facts",
                "operationId": "getFacts",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "max_length",
                        "in": "query",
                        "description": "maximum length of returned fact",
                        "required": false,
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int64"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "limit",
                        "in": "query",
                        "description": "limit the amount of results returned",
                        "required": false,
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "format": "int64"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CatFact"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "Breed": {
                "title": "Breed model",
                "description": "Breed",
                "properties": {
                    "breed": {
                        "title": "Breed",
                        "description": "Breed",
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "string"
                    },
                    "country": {
                        "title": "Country",
                        "description": "Country",
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "string"
                    },
                    "origin": {
                        "title": "Origin",
                        "description": "Origin",
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "string"
                    },
                    "coat": {
                        "title": "Coat",
                        "description": "Coat",
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "string"
                    },
                    "pattern": {
                        "title": "Pattern",
                        "description": "Pattern",
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "string"
                    }
                },
                "type": "object"
            },
            "CatFact": {
                "title": "CatFact model",
                "description": "CatFact",
                "properties": {
                    "fact": {
                        "title": "Fact",
                        "description": "Fact",
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "string"
                    },
                    "length": {
                        "title": "Length",
                        "description": "Length",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32"
                    }
                },
                "type": "object"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s no standard library but you could use [openapai3-parser](https://github.com/manchenkoff/openapi3-parser) to parse your openapi spec document and extract all necessary information. Check the documentation on GitHub on how to use it. You will probably need to convert json to yaml first using PyYAML or such library.

Comment: This is somewhat help @ankit. But all this gives is field wise & attribute wise object. I cannot find any function that returns entire API response body as a json string or json object. That is my initial requirement.